# "link" parameter for h2o.gbm

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, gbm

In H2O's gbm() function, is there any way to specify a particular link function for the offset? For example, if the distribution is set to "poisson", then I'd like to set the link to "log". This is certainly possible in h2o.glm(), but I don't see such an option in h2o.gbm().

Comment: No, see http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tutte/2/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/distribution.html

Comment: Got it, thanks for the link!